# Is $1_{[0,X(\omega)]}(y)$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, product-measure

About https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/s.g.cox/mtp_2017.pdf problem 5.11

" Let $F$ be a distribution function of a non-negative random variable $X$ and $\alpha>0$. Show that
\begin{align}
EX^{\alpha}  = \alpha\int_0^{\infty} x^{\alpha-1}(1-F(x))dx
\end{align} 
"

The hint they give is to write $EX^{\alpha} = Ef(X)$ with $f(x) = \int_0^x \alpha y^{\alpha-1}dy$.

So $EX^{\alpha} = \int \int_0^X \alpha y^{\alpha-1} dy dP$.

Now I want to use Fubini, but to do so, we need that $[0,\infty)\times \Omega: (y,\omega)\mapsto 1_{[0,X(\omega)]}(y)$ is measurable. Because then I can switch $dP$ and $d\lambda$ at $\int\int \alpha y^{\alpha-1} 1_{[0,X)}(y) d\lambda(y) dP$, where $\lambda$ is here the Lebesgue measure restricted on $[0,\infty)$.

If $y$ is given, then $1_{[0,X)}(y)$ is just a composition of an indicator function and $X$, so that is measurable. And if $\omega$ is given, then we also get an indicator function, but now dependable of $y$. But this says nothing about measurability in two dimensions.

I don't see a specified $\sigma$-algebra, so maybe we can just make one such that this function satisfies it (?)

Has anobody an idea how to deal with this? I thank in advance because I can't do that in the comments and of course I want to be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Show that the mapping $$\mathbb{R}^2 \ni (x,y) \mapsto g(x,y) := 1_{[0,x]}(y)$$ is (Borel)measurable. (Hint: It suffices to show that $g^{-1}(\{1\})$ is Borel.)
2. Show that the mapping $$\Omega \times \mathbb{R} \ni (\omega,y)  \mapsto h(\omega,y) :=(X(\omega),y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$ is measurable. (Here, $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the product $\sigma$-algebra.)
3. Conclude that $$(\omega,y) \mapsto 1_{[0,X(\omega)]}(y)$$ is measurable.

Comment: At the first one we get $g^{-1}(\lbrace 1\rbrace)$ being a triangle. This is the limit of block-sets in which the blocks get twice smaller every step (which I can't explain further) but it's dealable with a continuity property of measures. So (1) is measurable. The second is just applying that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and the third is composition.

Comment: @RoccovanVreumingen Not sure whether you get the second step right. How would you check measurability with respect to a product sigma-algebra?

Comment: Let $g$ be the function in step (2). 
If $B_1,B_2\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $g^{-1}(B_1\times B_2) = \lbrace X\in B_1\rbrace \times \lbrace y\in B_2\rbrace$ and that is in the product $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: Oh crap I meant " = $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ " so forgot the power of 2

Comment: @RoccovanVreumingen Yeah, that's okay.